# How can I filter on multiple NOT conditions in Django's ORM?

Tags: django, django-models

In Django 3.2, I have the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Employment(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    full_time = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Car(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The Goal: `Give me all people that drive a red car (unless they're a full-time firefighter)`

Here is what I thought would work:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    ~Q(employment__title='firefighter', employment__full_time=True),
    car__color='red'
)
```

However, this generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM "person"
INNER JOIN "car" ON ("person"."id" = "car"."owner_id")
WHERE "car"."color" = red
  AND (
    NOT (
      EXISTS(
        SELECT (1) AS "a"
        FROM "employment" U1
        WHERE U1."full_time"
          AND U1."owner_id" = "person"."id"
      )
      AND EXISTS(
        SELECT (1) AS "a"
        FROM "employment" U1
        WHERE U1."title" = firefighter
          AND U1."owner_id" = "person"."id"
      )
    )
```

This in effect returns all people that drive a red car (unless they are a firefighter OR have full-time employment). Like all other filter keys, I would have expected the two conditions on the foreign relation to be ANDED.

**Why the unexpected behavior? What's the right way to write this so the sql looks like this:?**

```
SELECT *
FROM "person"
INNER JOIN "car" ON ("person"."id" = "car"."owner_id")
WHERE "car"."color" = red
  AND (
    NOT (
      EXISTS(
        SELECT (1) AS "a"
        FROM "employment" U1
        WHERE U1."full_time",
          AND U1."title" = firefighter
          AND U1."owner_id" = "person"."id"
      )
    )
```

Comment: [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) .  It is the single most-awesome thing about Django ORM. You can compose them with bitwise `&` and `|` with parentheses groupings.  `Q(first) & Q(second) | (~Q(third) | (Q(fourth) & Q(fifth)))`

Comment: @RossRogers I thought of that. Try it yourself and you'll see it still creates the problem I listed. 
```Person.objects.filter(~Q(Q(employment__title='firefighter') & Q(employment__full_time=True)), car__color='red')``` <- Still splits the conditions making them ORs in effect

Comment: Just found the Django Ticket. This is a LONG standing bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14645

Comment: I would never use `filter()` `**kwargs` and `Q()`.  I'd use one or the other: `(~Q(employment__title='firefighter', employment__full_time=True)) & Q(car__color='red')`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe don't mix `Q()` and `**kwargs` to `filter()`:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    ~Q(employment__title='firefighter', employment__full_time=True) &
    Q(car__color='red')
)
```